# nokia web apps playing sound

Tags: javascript, nokia, nokia-s40, playsound

I have developed my first nokia web app . I am trying to play sound which saved in local storage  when button clicked

this is my code but it doesn't work

```
<div class="odd" id="g" onclick="playSound('s40-theme/sounds/piano_G.mp3')"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">     
    function playSound(file) {
    var embed = document.createElement("embed");

    embed.setAttribute('src', file);
    embed.setAttribute('hidden', true);
    embed.setAttribute('autostart', true);

    document.body.appendChild(embed);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because the **embed** tag is not supported in S40 Web Apps. [This page](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Nokia_Asha_web_apps_library/#!technical-library/html-tags-supported.html) lists all the supported tags.

The example given in [this FAQ](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Nokia_Asha_web_apps_-_FAQ) instructs you to use the *loadUrl* method. There is no way to play a sound in the background of the app. The following example will download the file and the user will play it in the native audio player.

Example:

`<a href="#" onclick="mwl.loadURL('path_to_file.mp3');">Play sound</a>`